# In group theory, do $ \langle\mathbb{Z}, +\rangle $ and $ \langle\mathbb{R}, +\rangle $ have the same order?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, group-isomorphism

Of course, $ \mathbb{Z} $ is countable, while $ \mathbb{R}$ is uncountable, so the two cannot be isomorphic. However, the reason for my question is the notation for the order of $ $$ \langle\mathbb{Z}, +\rangle $$ $ that I encountered recently, which said $ order($$ \langle\mathbb{Z}, +\rangle) $$ = \infty$.

If that notation is correct, my assumption is that $ \langle\mathbb{Z}, +\rangle $ and $ \langle\mathbb{R}, +\rangle $ have the same order.

Comment: What *order* are you talking about? Rigorous explanation with references would help a lot.

Answer (score 3):

If $G$ is a group then the order $\operatorname{ord}(g)$ of an *element* $g\in G$ is the smallest positive integer $n$ with $g^n=1$, or one (symbolically) writes $\operatorname{ord}(g)=\infty$ if no such integer exists.
The order of the *group* itself however is simply the cardinality of the underlying set. As such, one should never write $\infty$ for it, but rather $\aleph_0$ or $\mathfrak c$ or similar. Nevertheless, $\operatorname{ord}(G)<\infty$ to express that $G$ is a finite group is often found and might be acceptable.

Answer (score 2):

Saying that the order of $\mathbb{Z}$ is $\infty$ is just saying that $\mathbb{Z}$ is **not finite**. As you have already noted, $\mathbb{R}$ and $\mathbb{Z}$ are **not finite** in different ways (countable vs. uncountable).